# numpy: "size" vs. "shape" in function arguments?

Tags: python, numpy

I noticed that some numpy operations take an argument called `shape`, such as `np.zeros`, whereas some others take an argument called `size`, such as `np.random.randint`. To me, those arguments have the same function and the fact that they have different names is a bit confusing. Actually, `size` seems a bit off since it really specifies the `.shape` of the output.

Is there a reason for having different names, do they convey a different meaning even though they both end up being equal to the `.shape` of the output?

Comment: I don't think so. Its community developed. Its not always easy to ensure consistency. I agree with you. Shape (in the numpy context) seems to me the better option for an argument name. The actual relation between the two is `size = np.prod(shape)` so the distinction should indeed be a bit more obvious in the arguments names.

Comment: `randint` uses the `size` parameter name, but uses `shape` in the explanation.  This is not to be confused with a real `size` attribute.

Comment: I would suggest you to change the title to better reflect the fact that you talk about the *argument names* and not the attributes.

Comment: @Mayou36 Good suggestion. Done.

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Because the answer I find the most relevant is armatita's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804965/numpy-size-vs-shape-in-function-arguments?noredirect=1#comment76590338_44804965), and I cannot accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: Maybe you can encourage them to turn the comment into an answer!

Comment: Related thread on Github: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7387

Answer (score 12):

`Shape` relates to the size of the **dimensions** of an N-dimensional array.

`Size` regarding arrays, relates to the **amount** (or **count**) of elements that are contained in the array (or sometimes, at the top dimension of the array - when used as length).

For example, let `a` be a matrix

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

the shape of `a` is `(3, 4)`, the size of `a` is 12 and the size of `a[1]` is 4.

Comment: I think the OP understands that. He/She is questioning the choice of names for the arguments. For example `randint` asks for a size (int) but can actually take tuples (which in numpy is typically interpreted as a shape).

Comment: I think we could say that `a.shape.prod() = a.size`

Comment: @Euler_Salter, yes, but that's not the question. The question is about the *argument names* `shape` and `size`. And in the argument, they serve the same purpose and do not adhere to the relationship you pointed out. (they adhere to `shape` == `size`)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are working with a numpy array, which was seen as a C array, `size` refers to how big your array will be. Moreover, if you can pass `np.zeros(10)` or `np.zeros((10))`. While the difference is subtle, `size` passed this way will create you a 1D array. You can give `size=(n1, n2, ..., nn)` which will create an nD array.

However, because python users want multi-dimensional arrays, `array.reshape` allows you to get from 1D to an nD array. So, when you call `shape`, you get the N dimension shape of the array, so you can see exactly how your array looks like.

In essence, `size` is equal to the product of the elements of `shape`.

EDIT: The difference in name can be attributed to 2 parts: firstly, you can initialise your array with a size. However, you do not know the shape of it. So `size` is only for total number of elements. Secondly, how numpy was developed, different people worked on different parts of the code, giving different names to roughly the same element, depending on their personal vision for the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to explain with the `np.zeros(10)` vs `np.zeros((10))` difference. Did you mean `np.zeros((10, ))` (that is, the second one is actually a tuple)?

Answer (score 0):

Random array:

```
[[-2. -1.  0.  1.  2.]
 [-2. -1.  0.  1.  2.]
 [-2. -1.  0.  1.  2.]]
```

Here is the difference:

```
print(your_np_arr.shape)  # (3, 5)
print(your_np_arr.size)   # 15
```